# Know word at text insertion pointer on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know the word at the position of the text insertion pointer in a form on a webpage. My problem is that I don't really know what language to use to do this, and I have no idea how to do it in Javascript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

> get caret position javascript IE
>   firefox

http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/

Here is how to find moused over word on page

[How to get a word under cursor using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript)