# How can I strip all punctuation from a string in JavaScript using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string with any type of non-alphanumeric character in it:

```
"This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation"
```

How would I get a no-punctuation version of it in JavaScript:

```
"This is an example of a string with punctuation"
```

Answer (score 267):

If you want to remove specific punctuation from a string, it will probably be best to explicitly remove exactly what you want like

```
replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"")
```

Doing the above still doesn't return the string as you have specified it. If you want to remove any extra spaces that were left over from removing crazy punctuation, then you are going to want to do something like

```
replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
```

**My full example:**

```
var s = "This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation";
var punctuationless = s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
var finalString = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
```

**Results of running code in firebug console:**

[image]

Comment: Curly braces in regex apply a quantifier to the preceding, so in this case it's replacing between 2 and 100 whitespace characters (`\s`) with a single space. If you want to collapse any number of whitespace characters down to one, you would leave off the upper limit like so: `replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')`.

Comment: I've added a few more chars to list of punctuation replaced (`@+?><[]+`): `replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_\`~()@\+\?><\[\]\+]/g, '')`. If anyone is looking for a yet-slightly-more-complete set.

Comment: Python's string.punctuation defines punctuation as: ```!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~``` Which works better for me, so another alternative would be: ```replace(/['!"#$%&\\'()\*+,\-\.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]\^_`{|}~']/g,"");```

Comment: I think you're missing `[]` from the list of punctuation characters.

Comment: I think the part with `... ,-\/ ... ` in your regex is misleading. The `-` here will be interpreted like the range operator. You want:  `... ,\-\/ ... `. It doesn't make a difference in this case because you're trying to be comprehensive, but if you want to remove the period for instance it wouldn't work (because the period is within the range)

Comment: @AntoineLizée I agree that it's misleading. Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeGrace But now it's twice :-)

Comment: @AntoineLizée and that's what I get for not carefully rereading all my code.

Comment: @MikeGrace but what to do when you have "text?". Your replace will remove the word all together.

Comment: I've tried with "it?" - doesn't work for me (https://regex101.com/r/F4j5Qc/1), the right solution is: /[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()\?]/g

Comment: I know this is super old, but thank you! Had to find out the hard way why the for loop needs to run backwards :)

Comment: Just wanting to point out also that if you want to remove `[` and `]` then you'll need to add them into the `[]`, like so: `/[\[\]?.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g`

Comment: This is a bad answer. The question was "how do I remove **all punctuation** from a string?", not "how do I remove specific characters from a string?". Yes, there is a valid use case for this pattern, but it should not be the top+accepted answer without a better explanation for why.

Comment: 2020 update: all browsers now support unicode character classes in regexp... `var punctuationless = s.replace(/[^\p{L}\s]/gu,"");` works everywhere today.

Answer (score 188):

```
str = str.replace(/[^\w\s\']|_/g, "")
         .replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

Removes everything except alphanumeric characters and whitespace, then collapses multiple adjacent whitespace to single spaces.

Detailed explanation:

1. `\w` is any digit, letter, or underscore.
2. `\s` is any whitespace.
3. `[^\w\s\']` is anything that's not a digit, letter, whitespace, underscore or a single quote.
4. `[^\w\s\']|_` is the same as #3 except with the underscores added back in.

Comment: This will also strip out non-English but otherwise perfectly alphanumeric characters like à, é, ö, as well as the entire Cyrillic alphabet.

Comment: @quemeful I disagree, the original question does not specify "for english only". SO is quite international, used all over the world. Anyone who speaks English and has internet access can use it. If the language is not specified in the question, then we should not be making any assumptions. We are in 2017, dammit!

Comment: Also, even if you only support English you have loan words like résumé and names of places or people so you wouldn't want to break someone's ability to say they work in San José (the official spelling) in the cubicle between Ramón Chloé.

Comment: This will mess with words such as `wouldn't` and `don't`

Comment: what's the second `.replace(/\s+/g, " ");` accomplish here?

Comment: @njboot It collapses multiple adjacent whitespace to single spaces.

Comment: Agreed, @null. Corrected.

Comment: This doesn't work with it.  :(.  text = "The Fox asked the stork, 'How is the soup?'",

Comment: If you want to strip ALL punctuation, replace the regex in the first expression with this .. `/[^\w\s]/g`

Comment: This solution is terrible, strips away all kinds of characters: åæøá

Answer (score 82):

Here are the standard punctuation characters for US-ASCII: `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``

For Unicode punctuation (such as curly quotes, em-dashes, etc), you can easily match on specific block ranges. The **General Punctuation** block is `\u2000-\u206F`, and the **Supplemental Punctuation** block is `\u2E00-\u2E7F`.

Put together, and properly escaped, you get the following RegExp:

```
/[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/
```

That should match pretty much any punctuation you encounter. So, to answer the original question:

```
var punctRE = /[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/g;
var spaceRE = /\s+/g;
var str = "This, -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation";
str.replace(punctRE, '').replace(spaceRE, ' ');

>> "This is an example of a string with punctuation"
```

US-ASCII source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix

Unicode source: http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

Comment: For Unicode punctuation, the blocks are not enough. You have to look at the general category Punctuation, and you will see that not all punctuations are nicely located in those blocks. There are many familiar punctuations inside Latin blocks, for example.

Comment: Very useful answer, may not work for corner cases of some languages but better than earlier ones! Thanks

Answer (score 28):

As of 2021, many modern browsers support [JavaScript built-in: RegExp: Unicode property escapes](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes). So you can now simply use `\p{P}`:

```js
str.replace(/[\p{P}$+<=>^`|~]/gu, '')
```

The regex can be further simplified if you want to ignore all symbols (`\p{S}`) and punctuations.

```js
str.replace(str.replace(/[\p{P}\p{S}]/gu, '')
```

If you want to strip everything except letters (`\p{L}`), numbers (`\p{N}`) and separators (`\p{Z}`). You may use a negated character set like this (works for non-English alphanumeric characters too):

```js
str.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{Z}]/gu, '')
```

The above regex works, but more common use-case is to use regex whitespace class instead of Unicode separator character set as the latter does not include tabs and line feed. Try this:

```js
str.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/gu, '')
```

---

```js
const str = 'This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation';

console.log(str.replace(/[\p{P}$+<=>^`|~]/gu, ''));
console.log(str.replace(/[\p{P}\p{S}]/gu, ''));
console.log(str.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{Z}]/gu, ''));
console.log(str.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/gu, ''));
```

You may also like to chain a `.replace(/  +/g, ' ')` to [remove consecutive spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1981349/11613622).

Feel free to play around with these! **Ref:**
[Unicode Character Properties - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category)
[Unicode Property Escapes - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes)

Answer (score 16):

/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g should match all punctuation but keep the spaces.
So you can use `.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")` to replace extra spaces if you need to do so. You can test the regex in http://rubular.com/

```
.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")
```

**Update**: Will only work if the input is ANSI English.

Comment: You are assuming that the string is ANSI English. Not French with accented letters (àéô), nor German, Turkish. Unicode Arabic, Chinese, etc. will also disappear.

Comment: Thanks, did not think about that completely.

Answer (score 15):

I ran across the same issue, this solution did the trick and was very readable:

```
var sentence = "This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation";
var newSen = sentence.match(/[^_\W]+/g).join(' ');
console.log(newSen);
```

Result:

```
"This is an example of a string with punctuation"
```

The trick was to create a **negated set**. This means that it matches anything that is not within the set i.e. `[^abc]` - not *a, b* or *c*

`\W` is any non-word, so `[^\W]+` will negate anything that is not a word *char*.

By adding in the _ (underscore) you can negate that as well.

Make it apply globally `/g`, then you can run any string through it and clear out the punctuation:

```
/[^_\W]+/g
```

Nice and clean ;)

Comment: You also change all new lines into space with this method.

Comment: This method only works in English, all accented characters are removed.

Comment: @NicolasBernier yeah that's 100% correct - JavaScript's regex engine is actually pretty lame (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043307/why-this-regex-is-not-working-for-german-words) - unfortunately for more complex tasks (and to create patterns for non-English words) it takes a fair bit more code.

Still, for a quick & concise regex to strip punctuation it works :)

Comment: This was the simplest and served my purpose well.

Answer (score 12):

In a Unicode-aware language, the Unicode *Punctuation* character property is `\p{P}` — which you can usually abbreviate `\pP` and sometimes expand to `\p{Punctuation}` for readability.

Are you using a Perl Compatible Regular Expression library?

Comment: Unfortunately JS isn't Perl compatible. The other problem is when I tested this it didn't capture all of the punctuation in @Quentin's test string => http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/forums/stack-overflow/regex-punctuation-capture-not-capture-all.png

Comment: You can use the XRegExp library to get this extended syntax.

Comment: As of 2020, this should be the answer as modern browsers support the unicode character classes

Answer (score 11):

If you want to remove punctuation from any string you should use the `P` Unicode class.

But, because classes are not accepted in the JavaScript RegEx, you could try this RegEx that should match all the punctuation. It matches the following categories: Pc Pd Pe Pf Pi Po Ps Sc Sk Sm So GeneralPunctuation SupplementalPunctuation CJKSymbolsAndPunctuation CuneiformNumbersAndPunctuation.

I created it using [this online tool](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex#) that generates Regular Expressions specifically for JavaScript.
That's the code to reach your goal:

```js
var punctuationRegEx = /[!-/:-@[-`{-~¡-©«-¬®-±´¶-¸»¿×÷˂-˅˒-˟˥-˫˭˯-˿͵;΄-΅·϶҂՚-՟։-֊־׀׃׆׳-״؆-؏؛؞-؟٪-٭۔۩۽-۾܀-܍߶-߹।-॥॰৲-৳৺૱୰௳-௺౿ೱ-ೲ൹෴฿๏๚-๛༁-༗༚-༟༴༶༸༺-༽྅྾-࿅࿇-࿌࿎-࿔၊-၏႞-႟჻፠-፨᎐-᎙᙭-᙮᚛-᚜᛫-᛭᜵-᜶។-៖៘-៛᠀-᠊᥀᥄-᥅᧞-᧿᨞-᨟᭚-᭪᭴-᭼᰻-᰿᱾-᱿᾽᾿-῁῍-῏῝-῟῭-`´-῾\u2000-\u206e⁺-⁾₊-₎₠-₵℀-℁℃-℆℈-℉℔№-℘℞-℣℥℧℩℮℺-℻⅀-⅄⅊-⅍⅏←-⏧␀-␦⑀-⑊⒜-ⓩ─-⚝⚠-⚼⛀-⛃✁-✄✆-✉✌-✧✩-❋❍❏-❒❖❘-❞❡-❵➔➘-➯➱-➾⟀-⟊⟌⟐-⭌⭐-⭔⳥-⳪⳹-⳼⳾-⳿⸀-\u2e7e⺀-⺙⺛-⻳⼀-⿕⿰-⿻\u3000-〿゛-゜゠・㆐-㆑㆖-㆟㇀-㇣㈀-㈞㈪-㉃㉐㉠-㉿㊊-㊰㋀-㋾㌀-㏿䷀-䷿꒐-꓆꘍-꘏꙳꙾꜀-꜖꜠-꜡꞉-꞊꠨-꠫꡴-꡷꣎-꣏꤮-꤯꥟꩜-꩟﬩﴾-﴿﷼-﷽︐-︙︰-﹒﹔-﹦﹨-﹫！-／：-＠［-｀｛-･￠-￦￨-￮￼-�]|\ud800[\udd00-\udd02\udd37-\udd3f\udd79-\udd89\udd90-\udd9b\uddd0-\uddfc\udf9f\udfd0]|\ud802[\udd1f\udd3f\ude50-\ude58]|\ud809[\udc00-\udc7e]|\ud834[\udc00-\udcf5\udd00-\udd26\udd29-\udd64\udd6a-\udd6c\udd83-\udd84\udd8c-\udda9\uddae-\udddd\ude00-\ude41\ude45\udf00-\udf56]|\ud835[\udec1\udedb\udefb\udf15\udf35\udf4f\udf6f\udf89\udfa9\udfc3]|\ud83c[\udc00-\udc2b\udc30-\udc93]/g;
var string = "This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation";
var newString = string.replace(punctuationRegEx, '').replace(/(\s){2,}/g, '$1');
console.log(newString)
```

Answer (score 9):

I'll just put it here for others.

Match all punctuation chars for for all languages:

Constructed from Unicode punctuation category and added some common keyboard symbols like `$` and brackets and `\-=_`

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/list.htm

basic replace:

```
".test'da, te\"xt".replace(/[\-=_!"#%&'*{},.\/:;?\(\)\[\]@\\$\^*+<>~`\u00a1\u00a7\u00b6\u00b7\u00bf\u037e\u0387\u055a-\u055f\u0589\u05c0\u05c3\u05c6\u05f3\u05f4\u0609\u060a\u060c\u060d\u061b\u061e\u061f\u066a-\u066d\u06d4\u0700-\u070d\u07f7-\u07f9\u0830-\u083e\u085e\u0964\u0965\u0970\u0af0\u0df4\u0e4f\u0e5a\u0e5b\u0f04-\u0f12\u0f14\u0f85\u0fd0-\u0fd4\u0fd9\u0fda\u104a-\u104f\u10fb\u1360-\u1368\u166d\u166e\u16eb-\u16ed\u1735\u1736\u17d4-\u17d6\u17d8-\u17da\u1800-\u1805\u1807-\u180a\u1944\u1945\u1a1e\u1a1f\u1aa0-\u1aa6\u1aa8-\u1aad\u1b5a-\u1b60\u1bfc-\u1bff\u1c3b-\u1c3f\u1c7e\u1c7f\u1cc0-\u1cc7\u1cd3\u2016\u2017\u2020-\u2027\u2030-\u2038\u203b-\u203e\u2041-\u2043\u2047-\u2051\u2053\u2055-\u205e\u2cf9-\u2cfc\u2cfe\u2cff\u2d70\u2e00\u2e01\u2e06-\u2e08\u2e0b\u2e0e-\u2e16\u2e18\u2e19\u2e1b\u2e1e\u2e1f\u2e2a-\u2e2e\u2e30-\u2e39\u3001-\u3003\u303d\u30fb\ua4fe\ua4ff\ua60d-\ua60f\ua673\ua67e\ua6f2-\ua6f7\ua874-\ua877\ua8ce\ua8cf\ua8f8-\ua8fa\ua92e\ua92f\ua95f\ua9c1-\ua9cd\ua9de\ua9df\uaa5c-\uaa5f\uaade\uaadf\uaaf0\uaaf1\uabeb\ufe10-\ufe16\ufe19\ufe30\ufe45\ufe46\ufe49-\ufe4c\ufe50-\ufe52\ufe54-\ufe57\ufe5f-\ufe61\ufe68\ufe6a\ufe6b\uff01-\uff03\uff05-\uff07\uff0a\uff0c\uff0e\uff0f\uff1a\uff1b\uff1f\uff20\uff3c\uff61\uff64\uff65]+/g,"")
"testda text"
```

added \s as space

```
".da'fla, te\"te".split(/[\s\-=_!"#%&'*{},.\/:;?\(\)\[\]@\\$\^*+<>~`\u00a1\u00a7\u00b6\u00b7\u00bf\u037e\u0387\u055a-\u055f\u0589\u05c0\u05c3\u05c6\u05f3\u05f4\u0609\u060a\u060c\u060d\u061b\u061e\u061f\u066a-\u066d\u06d4\u0700-\u070d\u07f7-\u07f9\u0830-\u083e\u085e\u0964\u0965\u0970\u0af0\u0df4\u0e4f\u0e5a\u0e5b\u0f04-\u0f12\u0f14\u0f85\u0fd0-\u0fd4\u0fd9\u0fda\u104a-\u104f\u10fb\u1360-\u1368\u166d\u166e\u16eb-\u16ed\u1735\u1736\u17d4-\u17d6\u17d8-\u17da\u1800-\u1805\u1807-\u180a\u1944\u1945\u1a1e\u1a1f\u1aa0-\u1aa6\u1aa8-\u1aad\u1b5a-\u1b60\u1bfc-\u1bff\u1c3b-\u1c3f\u1c7e\u1c7f\u1cc0-\u1cc7\u1cd3\u2016\u2017\u2020-\u2027\u2030-\u2038\u203b-\u203e\u2041-\u2043\u2047-\u2051\u2053\u2055-\u205e\u2cf9-\u2cfc\u2cfe\u2cff\u2d70\u2e00\u2e01\u2e06-\u2e08\u2e0b\u2e0e-\u2e16\u2e18\u2e19\u2e1b\u2e1e\u2e1f\u2e2a-\u2e2e\u2e30-\u2e39\u3001-\u3003\u303d\u30fb\ua4fe\ua4ff\ua60d-\ua60f\ua673\ua67e\ua6f2-\ua6f7\ua874-\ua877\ua8ce\ua8cf\ua8f8-\ua8fa\ua92e\ua92f\ua95f\ua9c1-\ua9cd\ua9de\ua9df\uaa5c-\uaa5f\uaade\uaadf\uaaf0\uaaf1\uabeb\ufe10-\ufe16\ufe19\ufe30\ufe45\ufe46\ufe49-\ufe4c\ufe50-\ufe52\ufe54-\ufe57\ufe5f-\ufe61\ufe68\ufe6a\ufe6b\uff01-\uff03\uff05-\uff07\uff0a\uff0c\uff0e\uff0f\uff1a\uff1b\uff1f\uff20\uff3c\uff61\uff64\uff65]+/g)
```

added ^ to invert patternt to match not punctuation but the words them selves

```
".test';the, te\"xt".match(/[^\s\-=_!"#%&'*{},.\/:;?\(\)\[\]@\\$\^*+<>~`\u00a1\u00a7\u00b6\u00b7\u00bf\u037e\u0387\u055a-\u055f\u0589\u05c0\u05c3\u05c6\u05f3\u05f4\u0609\u060a\u060c\u060d\u061b\u061e\u061f\u066a-\u066d\u06d4\u0700-\u070d\u07f7-\u07f9\u0830-\u083e\u085e\u0964\u0965\u0970\u0af0\u0df4\u0e4f\u0e5a\u0e5b\u0f04-\u0f12\u0f14\u0f85\u0fd0-\u0fd4\u0fd9\u0fda\u104a-\u104f\u10fb\u1360-\u1368\u166d\u166e\u16eb-\u16ed\u1735\u1736\u17d4-\u17d6\u17d8-\u17da\u1800-\u1805\u1807-\u180a\u1944\u1945\u1a1e\u1a1f\u1aa0-\u1aa6\u1aa8-\u1aad\u1b5a-\u1b60\u1bfc-\u1bff\u1c3b-\u1c3f\u1c7e\u1c7f\u1cc0-\u1cc7\u1cd3\u2016\u2017\u2020-\u2027\u2030-\u2038\u203b-\u203e\u2041-\u2043\u2047-\u2051\u2053\u2055-\u205e\u2cf9-\u2cfc\u2cfe\u2cff\u2d70\u2e00\u2e01\u2e06-\u2e08\u2e0b\u2e0e-\u2e16\u2e18\u2e19\u2e1b\u2e1e\u2e1f\u2e2a-\u2e2e\u2e30-\u2e39\u3001-\u3003\u303d\u30fb\ua4fe\ua4ff\ua60d-\ua60f\ua673\ua67e\ua6f2-\ua6f7\ua874-\ua877\ua8ce\ua8cf\ua8f8-\ua8fa\ua92e\ua92f\ua95f\ua9c1-\ua9cd\ua9de\ua9df\uaa5c-\uaa5f\uaade\uaadf\uaaf0\uaaf1\uabeb\ufe10-\ufe16\ufe19\ufe30\ufe45\ufe46\ufe49-\ufe4c\ufe50-\ufe52\ufe54-\ufe57\ufe5f-\ufe61\ufe68\ufe6a\ufe6b\uff01-\uff03\uff05-\uff07\uff0a\uff0c\uff0e\uff0f\uff1a\uff1b\uff1f\uff20\uff3c\uff61\uff64\uff65]+/g)
```

for language like Hebrew maybe to remove " ' the single and the double quote. and do more thinking on it.

using this script:

step 1: select in Firefox holding control a column of U+1234 numbers and copy it, do not copy U+12456 they replace English

step 2 (i did in chrome)find some textarea and paste it into it then rightclick and click inspect.  then you can access the selected element with $0.

```
var x=$0.value
var z=x.replace(/U\+/g,"").split(/[\r\n]+/).map(function(a){return parseInt(a,16)})
var ret=[];z.forEach(function(a,k){if(z[k-1]===a-1 && z[k+1]===a+1) { if(ret[ret.length-1]!="-")ret.push("-");} else {  var c=a.toString(16); var prefix=c.length<3?"\\u0000":c.length<5?"\\u0000":"\\u000000"; var uu=prefix.substring(0,prefix.length-c.length)+c; ret.push(c.length<3?String.fromCharCode(a):uu)}});ret.join("")
```

step 3 copied over the first letters the ascii as separate chars not ranges because someone might add or remove individual chars

Answer (score 6):

For en-US ( American English ) strings this should suffice:

```
"This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation".replace( /[^a-zA-Z ]/g, '').replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' )
```

Be aware that if you support UTF-8 and characters like chinese/russian and all, this will replace them as well, so you really have to specify what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retain only alphabets and spaces, you can do:

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]+/g, '').replace('/ {2,}/',' ')
```

Comment: Won't that pull out more than just punctuation? Unicode and the like?

Comment: You mean "only **English** alphabets and spaces"

Answer (score 3):

if you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#words)

```
_.words('This, is : my - test,line:').join(' ')
```

This Example

```
_.words('"This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation"').join(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [Wikipedia's list of punctuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) I had to build the following regex which detects punctuations :

`[\.’'\[\](){}⟨⟩:,،、‒–—―…!.‹›«»‐\-?‘’“”'";/⁄·\&*@\•^†‡°”¡¿※#№÷×ºª%‰+−=‱¶′″‴§~_|‖¦©℗®℠™¤₳฿₵¢₡₢$₫₯֏₠€ƒ₣₲₴₭₺₾ℳ₥₦₧₱₰£៛₽₹₨₪৳₸₮₩¥]`

Comment: If using this regex, you should also escape your regex delimiter. For example, if you use `/` (most common) then it should be escaped inside the character class above by adding a back-slash before, like this: `\/`. This is how you would use it: `"String!! With, Punctuation.".replace(/[\.’'\[\](){}⟨⟩:,،、‒–—―…!.‹›«»‐\-?‘’“”'";\/⁄·\&*@\•^†‡°”¡¿※#№÷×ºª%‰+−=‱¶′″‴§~_|‖¦©℗®℠™¤₳฿₵¢₡₢$₫₯֏₠€ƒ₣₲₴₭₺₾ℳ₥₦₧₱₰£៛₽₹₨₪৳₸₮₩¥]+/g,"")`. By the way, I don't see the backtick (`) anywhere in there, how come?

Comment: ´ is missing. Seems to be hard to find a list of all punctuations.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution is:

```
.replaceAll(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,"");
```

Instead of filtering out every single non-character item, you just check if the character doesn't fit what you're looking for.

Comment: This strips away all characters that are no a-z, like æøå and even á, which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to return. I used this recently:

```
return text.match(/[a-z]/i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting a modern browsers (not IE) you can utilize unicode caracter classes. This is especially helpful when you also need to support caracters like german Umlaute (äöü) or else.

Here is what I ended up with. It replaces everything that is not a letter or apostrophe or whitespace and removes multiple whitespaces in row with a single one.

```js
const textStripped = text
  .replace(/[’]/g, "'") // replace ’ with '
  .replace(/[^\p{Letter}\p{Mark}\s']/gu, "") // remove everything that is not a letter, mark, space or '
  .replace(/\s+/g, " ") // remove multiple spaces
```

```js
.replace(/[’]/g, "'")
```

First replaces ’ (typographic apostrophe) with ' (typewriter apostrophe). As both may be used for words like "dont’t"

```js
.replace(/[^\p{Letter}\p{Mark}\s']/gu, "")
```

`\p{Letter}` stands for any caracter that is categorized as a letter in unicode.

The `\p{Mark}` category needs to be included to further cover letter mark combinations. For example a german ä can be encoded as a single caracter or as a combination of "a" and a Mark. This happens quite regularly when copying german texts from PDFs.

Source:
https://dev.to/tillsanders/let-s-stop-using-a-za-z-4a0m

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is:

```
str = str.replace(/[.,?\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()\s]/g, "");
```

Here I included question mark as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A weird way to do it is by using a loop that looks for characters in the string, then use a conditional that checkes if each character is either a number or letter, then throw the result in a new variable. For example;

```
let str = "hello!!!,.?"
let newStr = ''

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (/[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(str[i])) {
        newStr += str[i]
    }
}

console.log(newStr) //hello
```

Comment: It might be worth having a look at some of the other answers - they've used more of the full power of regex rather than using a loop and then comparing a single character at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple just replace character other than words:

```
.replace(/[^\w]/g, ' ')
```