# Using jQuery to find <em> tags and adding content within them

Tags: html, jquery

The users on my review type of platform highlight titles (of movies, books etc) in `<em class="title">` tags. So for example, it could be:

```
<em class="title">Pacific Rim</em>
```

Using jQuery, I want to grab the content within this em class and add it inside a hyperlink. To clarify, with jQuery, I want to get this result:

```
<em class="title"><a href="http://example.com/?=Pacific+Rim">Pacific Rim</a></em>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: JavaScript gets executed on the client-side, you shouldn't worry about performance.

Comment: @Matteo Yes, but poorly written JS can slow down the page for the user (which is what I was referring to).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/

Comment: Please update you original post with the new updated questions you had added in the comments under each answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ems = document.querySelectorAll("em.title");

for (var i = 0; i < ems.length; ++i) {
    if (ems[i].querySelector("a") === null) {
        var em = ems[i],
            text = jQuery(em).text();   
        var before = text[0] == " ";
        var after = text[text.length-1] == " ";
        text = text.trim();
        while (em.nextSibling && em.nextSibling.className && em.nextSibling.className.indexOf("title") != -1) {
            var tmp = em;
            em = em.nextSibling;
            tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);
            text += jQuery(em).text().trim();
            ++i;
        }
        var link = text.replace(/[^a-z \-\d']+/gi, "").replace(/\s+/g, "+");
        var innerHTML = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://domain.com/?=" + link + "\">" + text + "</a>";
        innerHTML = before ? " " + innerHTML: innerHTML;
        innerHTML = after ? innerHTML + " " : innerHTML;
        ems[i].innerHTML = innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t5efadk/)

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/1t5efadk/14/

Final: http://jsfiddle.net/186hwg04/8/

Comment: I am going to bounty this question with 100 points in 2 days when it is eligible. Can you help me make a complete answer? This is what is missing, see the fiddle with a few examples: http://jsfiddle.net/1t5efadk/1/ -- I want to remove "." and "," and most importantly "&" but keep single quotation marks and other characters. Remove html if its inside the tag. If 2 em tags are next to each other, then merge them. And if there is a link within the tag, then skip that tag. I think the fiddle explains it better.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson http://jsfiddle.net/1t5efadk/4/ - is this how you want it to work?

Comment: I am confused. The code in the new fiddle doesn't change the <em> tags at all?

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, there is one problem. The code should not strip special characters of the content, only the URL part. For example, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1t5efadk/7/ as you can see, it should display "Fast & Furious". The & characters should **only** be removed in the URL.

Comment: One minor change. Please change the regex that allows which characters to add numbers, and hyphen. For example, the title may be "X-Men"...

Comment: Also, the merger of EM tags is not working correctly, please see the first example in this fiddle and you will see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/1t5efadk/9/

Comment: I have one final request. Can you please update your questions and add a solution to allow single quotation marks within the URL, see the first item in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1t5efadk/11/ But please add a note of the solution at the end of the answer so that it is there if it is needed. That should definitely cover it!

Comment: Thank you so much!! How is this script in terms of performance?

Comment: Yes I know, sorry I deleted that comment as soon as I posted it when I noticed that your code worked already :) How is this script in terms of performance?

Comment: A performance test on your code VS another one shows that yours is 90% faster: http://jsperf.com/em-test Awesome! I'll mark this answer as correct and award it 100 points. There is just one minor issue that needs to be fixed. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/186hwg04/3/ As you see, it removes empty space at the end of the content of the EM tag, it shouldn't do this. It should remove it from the URL but not the content. Can you please fix this final issue so that we can finally put this answer to rest?! Note that I've change your code slightly and fixed an error, so please update code in fiddle.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/186hwg04/4/ and regarding performance, native js usually is faster than jquery :)

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution with the space issue does not work in common scenarios. Please see this fiddle as example: http://jsfiddle.net/186hwg04/7/ -- Your approach always adds spaces and therefore makes some sentences formatted incorrectly. Is there a better approach to fix the spacing issue? Sorry about bothering you with this so many times.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what exactly is going on at the end of the code? :D Is it checking *if* there is a space, then leave it? Thanks for the update.

Comment: The space needs to be outside tha <a> tag or the space will be underlined, so it checks if the text contains a space at beginning or end and then adds it outside the <a>.

Comment: Caeth, you will likely not respond to this but I thought I would ask anyway. We added this to our live site and found out another minor issue. If &nbsp; is added within the tag, then it doesn't work, see last paragraph in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/186hwg04/12/ -- is there anyway to make it work in instances when this character is added? Unfortunately, TinyMCE has a bad habit of adding this character all over the code.

Comment: You are king! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("em.title").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).text();
    var parameter_string = content.replace(/ /g, "+").trim();
    parameter_string = encodeURIComponent(parameter_string);
    var new_content = '<a href="http://domain.com/?s=' + parameter_string + '">' + content + '</a>';
    $(this).html(new_content);
});
```

If you want to remove any kind of punctuation, refer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex).

Comment: Thank you very much, although I have a question. Would it be better to use the wrapinner() function: http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/

Comment: When you want to replace the content of an HTML tag, you have to use `html`, `wrapInner` does a different thing.

Comment: 1+ Great answer but it has one flaw. You should update your code so that it removes any unnecessary empty spaces and special characters. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5feyh4n/ (note the extra + and comma that should not be added to the domain URL)...

Comment: I've added a `trim` and `encode` call in the JS because I don't think special characters should be removed. They are part of the book title or whatever it is and they should be passed to the new page.

Comment: I am going to bounty this question with 100 points in 2 days when it is eligible. Can you help me make a complete answer? This is what is missing, see the fiddle with a few examples: http://jsfiddle.net/u52rt6ad/1/ -- I want to remove "." and "," and most importantly "&" but keep single quotation marks and other characters. If 2 em tags are next to each other, then merge them. And if there is a link within the tag, then skip that tag. I think the fiddle explains it better.

Comment: Done except for the merge part, which is more difficult... http://jsfiddle.net/u52rt6ad/2/

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the merge part is the most important. The reason why is that it is a very common behavior among writers to highlight a word, and then highlight whichever letter they forgot, which sometimes results in two tags next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('em.title').html(function(i,html) {
  return $('<a/>',{href:'http://domain.com/?='+html.trim().replace(/\s/g,'+'),text:html});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<em class="title">Pacific Rim</em>
```

**UPDATE 1**

The following updated version will perform the following:

1. Grab the contents of the `em` element
2. Combine with the contents of the next element, if `em` and remove that element
3. Create a query string parameter from this with the following properties

   - Remove the characters `,.&`
   - Remove html
4. Append the query parameter to a predetermined URL and wrap the unmodified contents in an `e` element with the new URL.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Lx1Laurk/4/)

```
$('em.title:not(:has(a))').html(function() {
    $(this).append( $(this).next('em').html() ).next('em').remove();
    var text = $(this).text().trim().replace(/[\.,&]/g,'');
    return $('<a/>',{href:'http://domain.com/?par='+encodeURIComponent(text),html:$(this).html()});
});
```

Or [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Lx1Laurk/3/)

```
$('em.title:not(:has(a))').html(function() {
    $(this).append( $(this).next('em').html() ).next('em').remove();
    var text = $(this).text().trim().replace(/[\.,&]/g,'').replace(/\s/g,'+');
    return $('<a/>',{href:'http://domain.com/?par='+text,html:$(this).html()});
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Per the comments, the above versions have two issues:

1. Merge two elements that may be separated by a text node.
2. Process an `em` element that's wrapped in an `a` element.

The following version resolves those two issues:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Lx1Laurk/5/)

```
$('em.title:not(:has(a))').filter(function() { 
    return !$(this).parent().is('a'); 
}).html(function() {
    var nextNode = this.nextSibling;
    nextNode && nextNode.nodeType != 3 && 
        $(this).append( $(this).next('em').html() ).next('em').remove();
    var text = $(this).text().trim().replace(/[\.,&]/g,'').replace(/\s/g,'+');
    return $('<a/>',{href:'http://domain.com/?par='+text,html:$(this).html()});
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make it remove special characters? See this fiddle (see the comma issue in the URL): http://jsfiddle.net/1wujst29/2/

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need all special characters removed or specific charaters?

Comment: Alternatively instead of removing or replacing specific characters you could use `encodeURIComponent( html )`

Comment: I am going to bounty this question with 100 points in 2 days when it is eligible. Can you help me make a complete answer? This is what is missing, see the fiddle with a few examples: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx1Laurk/ -- I want to remove "." and "," and most importantly "&" but keep single quotation marks and other characters. Remove html if its inside the tag. If 2 em tags are next to each other, then merge them. And if there is a link within the tag, then skip that tag. I think the fiddle explains it better.

Comment: Sure, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Do you want the special characters (and html) removed only from the query string of `href` or also from the contents of the resulting `a`? `<a ...>?????</a>`

Comment: Only from the href string.

Comment: **Great** update. There are two issues though. It should only merge the em tags if the tags are literally next to each other. And if em tag is wrapped by a link, then it should not be affected either. I have added both examples here so that you can see the problem live: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DrhCy --- Also, what is the difference between the two demo codes you provided?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, I see exactly what you mean. Will take care of it in a flash.

Comment: Please take a look at update 2 and let me know if there's anything I missed.

Comment: This is outstanding, and works great. I have two questions before I accept this as correct and reward it with 100 points. 1. How do I add **target="_blank"** to the A tag. 2. In terms of performance and general good practice, is the solution in your answer better or the one posted by *caeth*?

Comment: 1. In the property list for the new `a` elements, `{href:...}`, you can provide a key/value pair for `target="_blank"` as follows: `{target:"_blank", href: ....}` 2. I am not able to give a conclusive answer regarding performance. I prepared a performance test here: http://jsperf.com/em-test but one of the tests is throwing an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null.` in Chrome and `TypeError: em.nextSibling is null.` in Firefox. Quite likely there's something I inputted wrongly.

Comment: Will you have a chance to look into why we are getting these errors?

Comment: Yes, I will and I'll let you know.

Comment: In @caeth answer I had to change `while (em.nextSibling.className && em....` to `while (em.nextSibling && em.nextSibling.className && em....` for the test to work. The test shows that @caeth's version is upto 90% faster than my version: http://jsperf.com/em-test

Answer (score 0):

Actually,if you just want to add a click event on `em.title`,I suggest you use like this:

```
$("em.title").click(function(){
    q = $(this).text()
    window.location.href = "http://www.domain.com/?="+q.replace(/ /g,"+")
}
```

you will use less html code on browser and this seems simply.

In addition you may need to add some css on `em.title`,like:

```
em.title{
     cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: This leads to some other problems, for example link not showing in statusbar makes some people don't want to click it.

Comment: You can add some css to decorate your `em` DOM, because usually hyperlink's default css can't finish our demand.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var link = $('em').text(); //or $('em.title') if you want
    var link2 = link.replace(/\s/g,"+");
    $('em').html('<a href="http://www.domain.com/?='+ link2 + '">' + link + '</a>');
});
```

Ofcourse you can replace the document ready with any type of handler

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.title').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    text = $this.text(),
    textEnc = encodeURIComponent(text);

  $this.empty().html('<a href="' + textEnc + '">' + text + '</a>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yoviluboqi/1/edit?html,js,output)