# Javascript regex to remove punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble with my regex. I'm sure something is not escaping properly.

```js
function regex(str) {
  
  str = str.replace(/(~|`|!|@|#|$|%|^|&|*|\(|\)|{|}|\[|\]|;|:|\"|'|<|,|\.|>|\?|\/|\\|\||-|_|+|=)/g,"")
  document.getElementById("innerhtml").innerHTML = str;
  
 }
```

```html
<div id="innerhtml"></div>

<p><input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="regex('test @ . / | ) this');">
```

Comment: Why not take a whitelist approach and only match alphanumeric characters?

Comment: I need to count all accented characters, so not sure how to handle whitelist approach.

Comment: @blasko whitelist approach would be slower.

Comment: I can see `{` `}` `*` `+` .... by the way `str.replace(/[~`\!@#$%^&\*\(\)\{\}\[\];:"'<,\.>\?\/\\\|\-_\+=]+/g,"")` seems to work - not sure which is easier to read

Comment: @Daniel Why Don't you try escaping everything, Escaping doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` and `+` needs to be escaped.

```js
function regex (str) {
    return str.replace(/(~|`|!|@|#|$|%|^|&|\*|\(|\)|{|}|\[|\]|;|:|\"|'|<|,|\.|>|\?|\/|\\|\||-|_|\+|=)/g,"")
}

var testStr = 'test @ . / | ) this'
document.write('<strong>before: </strong>' + testStr)
document.write('<br><strong>after: </strong>' + regex(testStr))
```

Comment: The answer on the linked duplicate is better. It makes more sense to put the characters in a `[matching group]` than it does to `a|or|b` them.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer on [the question proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex) doesn't cover all the punctuation characters in ASCII range. (The comment on the accepted answer does, though).

A better way to write this regex is to use put the characters into a character class.

```
/[~`!@#$%^&*(){}\[\];:"'<,.>?\/\\|_+=-]/g
```

In a character class, *to match the literal characters*:

- `^` does not need escaping, unless it is at the beginning of the character class.
- `-` should be placed at the beginning of the character class (after the `^` in a negated character class) or at the end of a character class.
- `]` has to be escaped to be specified as literal character. `[` does not need to be escaped (but I escape it anyway, as a habit, since some language requires `[` to be escaped inside character class).
- `$`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `|`, `.` loses their special meaning inside character class.

In RegExp literal, `/` has to be escaped.

In RegExp, since `\` is the escape character, if you want to specify a literal `\`, you need to escape it `\\`.