# How do I test if a string kind of equals another javascript

Tags: javascript, string, string-comparison

Say I have var `string1 = "Hello"` and `string2 = "Hello"`
How can I compare these two and ignore the capitals and the punctuation in javascript?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Use `String.toLowerCase()` to lowercase a string. To remove punctuation, see this post: [How can I strip all punctuation from a string in JavaScript using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex#4328722)

Then compare with the `===` operator. For example:

```
var string1 = "Hello";
var string2 = "Hello";

string1 = string1.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
string2 = string2.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");

if (string1.toLowerCase() === string2.toLowerCase()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Or `.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "");`. And where is the semicolons `;`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I don’t use semicolons but I’ll add them

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Also you aren’t accounting for capitals and numbers with that regex

Comment: Just a word of advice: **ALWAYS USE THE FREAKING SEMICOLONS OR ONE DAY YOU'LL REGRET IT**!

Comment: I don't think numbers are important and for the lower/upper case thing you can use the `i` modifier!