# How to differentiate each of the character in string

Tags: vb.net

I got a question in vb.net
can I identify each of the character in string
for an example
i got a string of "Hello!. Good Afternoon!"

from this string can i trim away the period symbol?
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. Do you want to Remove all the `.`? Remove the 7th char of the string? Remove any consecutive Ponctuation (ex:`"1...2"` -> `"1.2"`? What will be the expected Output on `"//1..2..--.3!!"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the methods of the [**`String`** class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx), as they support different forms of string manipulation.

At its simplest, the [**`Replace()`** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to replace all occurrences of a period character with an empty string.

Alternatively, you can use the `IndexOf()` method to locate a specific string (e.g. the period) and the `Remove()` method to remove that character.

Answer (score 0):

According to my 8-ball Magic, you actually want to :

#### Remove concecutive punctuation from a string:

1. With a [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328546/6560478) we are going to find all punctuation in the string.
2. The index of Match will be into an `int[]`.
3. We will go iterate throught the array to find if the index is concecutive to the last punctuation index.
4. We will delete all the punctuation starting by the last one. Because starting with the 1rst will modify the index.

Code:

```
string Input = "....Thalassius! vero ea--*/-*/-- tempestate+- fectus";
string Output = Input;

var regex = new Regex(@"[^\w\s]|_");    // *1.
var matches = regex.Matches(Input) ;
var MatchesIndex = matches  .Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(match => match.Index)
                            .ToArray();    // *2.

int last = 0;
List<int> toDelete = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < MatchesIndex.Length; i++)    // *3.
{
    if ( MatchesIndex[i] == last + 1)
        toDelete.Add(MatchesIndex[i]);
    last = MatchesIndex[i];
}

foreach (int i in toDelete.OrderByDescending(x => x))    // *4.
    Output = Output.Remove(i, 1);

Console.WriteLine("Input : " + Input);
Console.WriteLine("Output : " + Output);
```

[C# Snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B1Jc3n)

You can [learn more about the regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328546/6560478) used, thanks to @John Kugelman.