# Check for Palindromes on freecode camp (don't want solution)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be clear I'm not looking for solutions. I'm really trying to understand what is being done. With that said all pointers and recommendations are welcomed. I am woking through freecodecamp.com task of Check for Palindromes. Below is the description.

> Return true if the given string is a palindrome. Otherwise, return
>   false.
>
> A palindrome is a word or sentence that's spelled the same way both
>   forward and backward, ignoring punctuation, case, and spacing.
>
> Note You'll need to remove all non-alphanumeric characters
>   (punctuation, spaces and symbols) and turn everything lower case in
>   order to check for palindromes.
>
> We'll pass strings with varying formats, such as "racecar", "RaceCar",
>   and "race CAR" among others.
>
> We'll also pass strings with special symbols, such as "2A3*3a2", "2A3
>   3a2", and "2_A3*3#A2".

This is what I have for code right now again I'm working through this and using chrome dev tools to figure out what works and what doesn't.

```
function palindrome(str) {
  // Good luck!
str = str.toLowerCase();
 //str = str.replace(/\D\S/i);
str = str.replace(/\D\s/g, "");

for (var i = str.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
str += str[i];
}


palindrome("eye");
```

What I do not understand is when the below code is run in dev tools the "e" is missing.

str = str.replace(/\D\s/g, "");
"raccar"

So my question is what part of the regex am I miss understanding? From my understand the regex should only be getting rid of spaces and integers.

Comment: Paste your regexp into regex101.com and read the description carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/\D\s/g` is replacing any character not a digit, followed by a space with "".

So, in `race car`, the Regex matches `"e "` and replaces it with "", making the string `raccar`

For digit, you need to use `\d`. I think using an `OR` would get you what you want. So, you may try something like `/\d|\s/g` to get a digit or a space.

Hope this helps in some way in your understanding!

Comment: ahh, ok thanks, that makes perfect since. I didn't realize I could use the or "|" in there. This should move me forward thanks.

Comment: What about the given test case of `2_A3*3#A2`?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex) can help for that.