# How to remove *.*, */* from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to remove fractional addresses from a street address input line. I need to allow for people who enter strings like the following:

- 1600 1/2 Main St
- 1600 3/4 Main Street
- 1600.5 Main St
- 1600.75 3rd Street

The above examples should be output as follows:

- 1600 Main St
- 1600 Main Street
- 1600 Main St
- 1600 3rd Street

Here's what I've started with:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('billing_address_1');

if (typeof(ele) != 'undefined' && ele != null) {
    function fractionalAddress() {
        originalStreet = ele.value;

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex
        //var punctuationless = originalStreet.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
        //var finalStreet = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");

        finalStreet = originalStreet.replace(/\s.*\//, '');          

        ele.value = finalStreet;
        console.log(originalStreet);
        console.log(finalStreet);
    };

    ele.addEventListener("change", fractionalAddress);
}
```

I haven't quite figured out how to grab the character after the slash but before the space. So, the above converts "1600 3/4 Main Street" into "16004 Main Street." Close, but not quite there!

What am I missing? Would it be better to split this into an array?

Comment: i thing you will need lookaheads

Comment: weird you would remove that from a valid address..... Add numbers to your regexp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me with the help of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/d2BuYb/1)

```js
var addresses = `1600 1/2 Main St
1600 3/4 Main Street
1600.5 Main St
1600.75 3rd Street`

console.log(
addresses.replace(/ ?\d\/\d?|\.\d{1,}/g,"")
)
```

breakdown:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to work.

```
finalStreet = originalStreet.replace(/\s*(\d+\/\d+|\.\d+)\s/g, '');
```

A tip for the future, you can use a site like regex101.com to test and edit your regex