# Remove all punctuation from string except for ' character

Tags: javascript

Following this question [How can I strip all punctuation from a string in JavaScript using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex) I'm trying to remove all punctuation from a string besides the `'` character to avoid messing with words such as:

- wouldn't
- don't
- won't

So far I have tried the following:

```
return word.replace(/[^\w\s]|_\'/g, "")
          .replace(/\s+/g, " ");;
```

But it is still removing the `'` character. Any idea how I can achieve such a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the escaped apostrophe to the excluded character class: `/[^\w\s\']|_/g`

Answer (score 0):

Add the apostrophe to your regex like this, in the exclusion block:

```js
const str = "This., -/is #! a ;: {} = - string$%^&* which `~)() doesn't, have any)( punctuation!";

const noPunctation = str.replace(/[^\w\s']|_/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

console.log(noPunctation);
```