# How to check if a string contains a WORD in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, split

So, you can easily check if a string contains a particular substring using the .includes() method.

I'm interested in finding if a string contains a word.

For example, if I apply a search for "on" for the string, "phones are good", it should return false. And, it should return true for "keep it on  the table".

Comment: E.g. simply allow white space on each side of the _word_, or use `\bword\b`

Answer (score 17):

You first need to convert it into array using `split()` and then use `includes()`

```
string.split(" ").includes("on")
```

Just need to pass whitespace `" "` to `split()` to get all words

Comment: What if the words are separated by a comma?

Comment: This won't work if the word is followed by a comma

Comment: `.includes()` works on strings as well as arrays, so `.split()` isn't needed.

Comment: @adiga OP didn't asked for the seperation of `,`

Comment: @Scott Marcus yes it works on the strings but he want to match whole word. And includes on string doesnot match whole word

Comment: It does if the search string has space delimiters: `string.includes(" on ")` or `string.includes(" on.")`. As others have mentioned RegExp would be best.

Comment: No that will cause problems if the `on` is in last or start

Comment: See my edited comment. Because `string.split(" ")` has the same problems.

Comment: @Scott Marcus I know but I didn't wanted to use regex.I would like to know those problems.Give examples where it would fail.

Comment: It would fail if the words weren't delimited by spaces.

Comment: @Scott Marcus Means more than one space?

Comment: No, I mean: `var theString = "apple,orange-banana;grapefruit"`

Comment: @Scott Marcus but OP didn't asked that his string will separated by `,-;`

Answer (score 6):

This is called a [regex - regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_regexp.asp)

You can use of [101regex](https://regex101.com/) website when you need to work around them *(it helps)*. Words with custom separators aswell.

---

```js
function checkWord(word, str) {
  const allowedSeparator = '\\\s,;"\'|';

  const regex = new RegExp(
    `(^.*[${allowedSeparator}]${word}$)|(^${word}[${allowedSeparator}].*)|(^${word}$)|(^.*[${allowedSeparator}]${word}[${allowedSeparator}].*$)`,

    // Case insensitive
    'i',
  );
  
  return regex.test(str);
}

[
  'phones are good',
  'keep it on the table',
  'on',
  'keep iton the table',
  'keep it on',
  'on the table',
  'the,table,is,on,the,desk',
  'the,table,is,on|the,desk',
  'the,table,is|the,desk',
].forEach((x) => {
  console.log(`Check: ${x} : ${checkWord('on', x)}`);
});
```

---

**Explaination** :

I am creating here multiple capturing groups for each possibily :

`(^.*\son$)` on is the last word

`(^on\s.*)` on is the first word

`(^on$)` on is the only word

`(^.*\son\s.*$)` on is an in-between word

`\s` means a space or a new line

```js
const regex = /(^.*\son$)|(^on\s.*)|(^on$)|(^.*\son\s.*$)/i;

console.log(regex.test('phones are good'));
console.log(regex.test('keep it on the table'));
console.log(regex.test('on'));
console.log(regex.test('keep iton the table'));
console.log(regex.test('keep it on'));
console.log(regex.test('on the table'));
```

---

Comment: Fails on strings that end with a period.  For example "keep it on."

Comment: ```regex = new RegExp('\b${word}\b')``` is way simpler

Answer (score 4):

You can `.split()` your string by spaces (`\s+`) into an array, and then use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if the array of strings has your word within it:

```js
const hasWord = (str, word) => 
  str.split(/\s+/).includes(word);
  
console.log(hasWord("phones are good", "on"));
console.log(hasWord("keep it on the table", "on"));
```

If you are worried about punctuation, you can remove it first using `.replace()` (as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex) answer) and then `split()`:

```js
const hasWord = (str, word) => 
  str.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"").split(/\s+/).includes(word);
  
console.log(hasWord("phones are good son!", "on"));
console.log(hasWord("keep it on, the table", "on"));
```

Comment: Looks like a good answer to me. No idea why ppl downvote this without giving their 2cents. Upvoting it.

Comment: @MarciaOng thanks :) glad I wasn’t the only one thinking the -1 was unjustified

Comment: @NickParsons great answer. People should read and understand before voting. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can split and then try to find:

```js
const str = 'keep it on the table';
const res =  str.split(/[\s,\?\,\.!]+/).some(f=> f === 'on');
console.log(res);
```

In addition, `some` method is very efficient as it will return true if **any** predicate is true.

Comment: and when it has !,.,; etc?

Comment: @epascarello thanks for great comment! I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.includes()` and check for the word. To make sure it is a word and not part of another word, verify that the place you found it in is followed by a space, comma, period, etc and also has one of those before it.

Comment: or better use regex

Comment: @Aarif also a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple version could just be splitting on the whitespace and looking through the resulting array for the word:

```
"phones are good".split(" ").find(word => word === "on") // undefined

"keep it on the table".split(" ").find(word => word === "on") // "on"
```

This just splits by whitespace though, when you need parse text (depending on your input) you'll encounter more word delimiters than whitespace. In that case you could use a regex to account for these characters. 
Something like:

```
"Phones are good, aren't they? They are. Yes!".split(/[\s,\?\,\.!]+/)
```

Answer (score -2):

I would go with the following assumptions:

1. Words the start of a sentence always have a trailing space.
2. Words at the end of a sentence always have a preceding space.
3. Words in the middle of a sentence always have a trailing and preceding space.

Therefore, I would write my code as follows:

```js
function containsWord(word, sentence) {
    return (
       sentence.startsWith(word.trim() + " ") ||
       sentence.endsWith(" " + word.trim()) ||
       sentence.includes(" " + word.trim() + " "));
}

console.log(containsWord("test", "This is a test of the containsWord function."));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following -

```js
var mainString = 'codehandbook'
var substr = /hand/
var found = substr.test(mainString)
if(found){
  console.log('Substring found !!')
} else {
  console.log('Substring not found !!')
}
```