# what is best way to match words from list to words from sentence in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, string-matching

i have two sentences and i would like to find all the words they share regardless of capitalization or punctuation.
currently this is what I am doing:

```
    searchWords = sentence1.split(" ");
    var wordList = sentence2.split(" ");
    const matchList = wordList.filter(value => -1 !== searchWords.indexOf(value));
```

it works ok but obviously capitalization and punctuation cause issues. 
i know i need to incorporate something like .match() in there but i don't know how to work with it. I am sure this is something someone has done before just havent found the code yet, any refrences are also appreciated.

Thank you,

Best

This dude.

Comment: compare by convert to lowercase like this searchWords.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for **any words that match** you can use `RegExp` with `String.prototype.replace` and verify a match using `String.prototype.search` with a created `RegExp` and an `i` flag to allow case insensitivity.

```js
function compare(str1, str2, matches = []) {
     str1.replace(/(\w+)/g, m => str2.search(new RegExp(m, "i")) >= 0 && matches.push(m));
     return matches;
 }
 
 console.log( compare("Hello there this is a test", "Hello Test this is a world") );
```

---

If you're looking for **specific words that match** you can use `functional composition` to `split` each string into an `Array`, filter each by possible `matches`, and then filter one against the other.

```js
function compare(str1, str2, matchables) {
     let containFilter = (a) => (i) => a.includes(i),
     matchFilter = s => s.toLowerCase().split(" ").filter(containFilter(matchables));
     
    return matchFilter(str1).filter(containFilter( matchFilter(str2) ));
 }
 
 let matchables = ["hello", "test", "world"];
 console.log( compare("Hello there this is a test", "Hi Test this is a world", matchables) );
```

Comment: compare("Chapter 1 test.", "Chapter one test") first example doesn't work correctly for this, only matches test

Comment: @TadewosBellete Thanks for letting me know! I simply used a `>` operator instead of a `>=` on the index check.

Comment: Thanks dude! can i add an expressing in the new RegExp(m,'i') to make it ignore punctuation?

Comment: @TadewosBellete sure. There are a few ways to do it. You can strip the string of these punctuation characters before the search,  OR you can adjust the RegEx manually.  `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_] ` - so if you want to remove the underscore as an option simply change it to `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - but this all depends on your use case. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over-thinking this. Would just converting both sentences to an array and using a for loop to cycle through the words work? For example:

```
var searchWords = sentence1.split(" ");
var wordList = sentence2.toLowerCase().split(" ");
var commonWords = [];
for(var i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++){
    if(wordList.includes(searchWords[i].toLowerCase())){
        commonWords.push(searchWords[i])
    }
}
console.log(commonWords);
```

Or some variation of that.

As for the punctuation, you could probably add `.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g,"")` to the end of `searchWords[i].toLowerCase()` as mentioned in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33408855/10601203

Comment: yea haha maybe you 're  right, working well but punctuation is not ignore. Might not need it to be tho.

Comment: I added an edit for the punctuation. You can add `.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g,"")` to the end of `searchWords[i].toLowerCase()` as mentioned in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33408855/10601203