# RegularExpressionAttribute javascript encoding

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, custom-attributes

Let's say you have a property Name in your ViewModel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]       
[RegularExpressionAttribute("[a-zA-Z äöåÄÖÅ]+", ErrorMessage = "Field {0} must contain only letters.")]      
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

In some browser this works as it's not getting encoded:

```
<input class="name valid" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Field Name must contain only letters." data-val-regex-pattern="[a-zA-Z äöåÄÖÅ]+" data-val-required="Name is required." name="Name" type="text" value="">
```

But in some browsers this gets encoded so the regex doesn't work

```
<input class="name valid" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Field Name must contain only letters." data-val-regex-pattern="[a-zA-Z &amp;#228;&amp;#246;&amp;#229;&amp;#196;&amp;#214;&amp;#197;]+" data-val-required="Name is required." name="Name" type="text" value="">
```

I've investigated and found out that javascript has problems
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4044768/1241400.

Is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Unicode escapes:

```
"[A-Za-z \\u00E4\\u00F6\\u00E5\\u00C4\\u00D6\\u00C5]+"
```

Comment: I've just tested it in IE 8+ and Firefox 6+ and it's working. Great solution, thanks.