# JS: how to split sentence in words with special characters and punctuations

Tags: javascript, regex

For Example:

The `words = "Hallo, über Wörterbuch?!";` should be splitted in to an array list as:

`["Hallo", ",", "über", "Wörterbuch", "?!"]`

But with `words.split(/\s|\b/g)`, I will only get

`["Hallo", ",", "ü", "ber", "W", "ö", "rterbuch", "?!"]`

So it seems that the "ö" has been considered as the boundary. Is there any solution for solving this kind of problem? Thank you in advance!

> **Sorry, please don't close this question, none of the existing questions work with my case, unless you can give an answer.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043307/why-this-regex-is-not-working-for-german-words

Comment: Yes, there is a word boundary between `W` and `ö` because `\b` is not Unicode-aware.

Comment: sorry, please don't close this question, none of the existing questions work with my case, unless you can give an answer.