# google translator highlight effect

Tags: highlighting, google-translate

I looked all over for a code that will that would highlight a piece of text when I hover (or click) another text.

For instance if I have the text 'Je suis ici. I am here', when i hover the word 'here' I will have a yellow bachground for the word 'here' and for the word 'ici'. So I can show that the word here is the english corespondent for the french word 'ici'.

Something like google translator uses: http://translate.google.com/

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!
Dana.

Comment: I assume you want this on the web using CSS or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The way that Google Translate does it, is to split up each word in a sentence into separate `<span>` tags with matching classes. These are then accessible via the DOM in JavaScript - most easily by using a framework such as JQuery.

For example, you could attach a `mouseover()` function to highlight the currently hovered word.

I can't give you a full example here - you'll need to come up with a starting point and develop your solution from there.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) library and is borrowed heavily from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript/2444462#2444462) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript).

What it does is break up each word in a paragraph tag (`<p>`) and wrap it with a `<span>` tag with a class of `highlightable` and then attach an event on hover to the `<span class='highlightable'>` tags.  If you want only one paragraph to be used, then give it an ID and bind only to those items in that given ID.  If a few paragraphs, use a class or multiple IDs.

```
<p>Each word will be wrapped in a span.</p>
<p>A second paragraph here.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // wrap words in spans
        $("p").each(function() {
            $(this).text().
                replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span class='highlightable'>$1</span>");
        });

        // bind to each highlightable span
        $('.highlightable').hover(
            function() { $(this).css('background-color','#ffff66'); },
            function() { $(this).css('background-color',''); }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: uf..this is way over my head :) 
All I get from this is this:

<style>
.highlightable:hover{background-color: #ffff66}
</style>

<p>bla bla <span class='highlightable'>word</span> bla bla <span class='highlightable'>word2</span> </p>

But then what..?

Comment: @Dana - if you already have the words in the span with class highlightable and you have the hover, then you should be able to use it as is.  It's getting the words into the spans that may be an issue.  You might want to read up on CSS, HTML, and Javascript to get an idea of how they work together.