# Retrieve text value when hover over text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched everywhere but can't find it. So I'm asking it here. I want to get the text when the mouse is on top (hover) of that text inside an html page. I tried using getClientRect, but they only give me coordinates, and not text. Does anybody know how to do this with javascript or html? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you give us an HTML markup???? What kind of text is it? how many "texts" do you have in the page?

Comment: ...*searched everywhere but can't find it*  hmmm?

Comment: here's an example

<html>
<body>
hello, i am new
</body>
</html>

So when I hover my mouse over "am", I would be able to retrieve "am"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what element you're trying to get the text for, but possibly what you want to do is use the mouseenter event.

```
$(parentselector).on({
    'mouseenter': function(){
            alert($(this).html()); // .html() or .val() depending on the element
        }
    },
    targetselector
);
```

EDIT:

[How to get a word under cursor using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript)

Create your HTML like this

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <span class="word">Hello</span>
      <span class="word">I</span>
      <span class="word">am</span>
      <span class="word">new</span>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then something like this in jQuery.

```
$('body').on({
    'mouseenter': function(){
            var txt = $(this).html();
        }
    },
    'span.word'
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but doesn't that bring back all the text inside an element? I just want one word inside the array of text nodes.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got access to jQuery, you can use the [.mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event handler. You can bind it to a specific DOM element and then grab the value either through val, or innerhtml.

Comment: But the innerhtml brings back all the text, I just need the text that the mouse is over.

Comment: Not sure there is a way to do that other than wrapping each word (or sentence -- depending on your circumstances) in a span element with a class event handler attached to it. -- Just noticed James Hay's response. Much better!