# Phantomjs - Finding words at a given coordinate on rendered pages

Tags: phantomjs, html-rendering

Using PhantomJs, I am trying to find out which single word is rendered at a given x/y-coordinate on a web page. I have seen several examples of achieving such localizations at object level, but I am looking for a way of breaking it down to term-level precision.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This basically involves finding the bounds of all the words on the page, and then figuring out which one contains said point. This is nearly identical to finding the word under the cursor, which has been thoroughly answered in this question: [How to get a word under cursor using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript)