# Getting specific word or sentence tapped inside UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, uiwebview

My app has a UIWebView that allows the user the surf the web (big surprise).
I want to be able to recognize the word the user taps on.

I can recognize the HTML element being tapped on using `document.elementFromPoint` but I want to recognize the specific word or sentence.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript