# the boundingClientRect of range not calculate properly when using range.expand('word') in inline elements

Tags: javascript, html, range, getboundingclientrect

I'm working on a chrome translate extension that when holding the ctrl key for seconds,the extension get the word under the cursor,translate it,and then display the result on the top of the word.

When dealing with getting the word under the cursor,I first need to create the range of the word under the cursor.I use the following code snippet to achieve this.I reference to here.https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710561/4244369

```
var getRangeAtPoint = function(elem, x, y) {
    if (elem.nodeType == elem.TEXT_NODE) {
        var range = elem.ownerDocument.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(elem);
        var currentPos = 0;
        var endPos = range.endOffset;
        while (currentPos + 1 < endPos) {
            range.setStart(elem, currentPos);
            range.setEnd(elem, currentPos + 1);
            var range_rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
            if (range_rect.left <= x && range_rect.right >= x &&
                range_rect.top <= y && range_rect.bottom >= y) {
                range.expand("word");
                return range;
            }
            currentPos += 1;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var range = elem.childNodes[i].ownerDocument.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(elem.childNodes[i]);
            var range_rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
            if (range_rect.left <= x && range_rect.right >= x &&
                range_rect.top <= y && range_rect.bottom >= y) {
                range.detach();
                var computed_range = getRangeAtPoint(elem.childNodes[i], x, y);
                if(computed_range){
                    return computed_range;
                }
            } else {
                range.detach();
            }
        }
    }
    return (null);
};
```

After creating the range,I can use `range.toString()` to get the word and `range.getBoundingClientRect()` to decide the position to display the result.It works well until I met the following case:

```
<p>click the <a href='#'>sample words</a> here</p>
```

If the cursor is under the word "words",it works properly.However,when the cursor is under the word "sample",after calling `range.expand('word')`,the client rect is wrong,the width of client rect should be the width of "sample",however,it's the width of "sample words".

I also include a jsfiddle here.https://jsfiddle.net/sangelee/1maqmm89/

Is it the problem of `range.expand('word')`?How to fix it?Or instead of using `range.expand('word')`,are there any way to achieve this?Any help is appreciated!ps.I'm using chrome 39.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `range.expand()`, as you suspected. Also, the code to get the caret position as a range can be vastly simplified. Example (WebKit only):

https://jsfiddle.net/e5knrLv8/

The console also reveals that `range.expand()`, which has always been a WebKit-only non-standard method, has been deprecated in favour of [`Selection.modify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify), which unfortunately is a bit of a pain to use in practice. Here is a revised example using `Selection.modify`, which does fix your issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/e5knrLv8/1/

Comment: The `caretRangeFromPoint` method simplified my work a lot !!And your workaround of using `Selection.modify` works perfectly if the following spaces of the word were not included in the selection.@TimDown

Comment: How to remove the following spaces of the word after calling `selection.modify('extend','forward','word')`? @Tim

Comment: I found that after calling `range.expand('word')`,the range's properties(startOffset,endOffset,startContainer,endContainer) seems to be set correctly.And I also have found this:[https://github.com/edg2s/rangefix](https://github.com/edg2s/rangefix).