# Toggle display hidden/block for many divs via different spans only with css

Tags: html, css, hover, hidden

For my japanes learning site i am building a kana-helper: Every time when the cursor hovers over a kana (basic japanese characters)  in the text, the belonging romaji should be shown in a fixed div.

I am a very beginner in css and html etc. and with the [help of this community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320432/get-a-word-under-cursor-and-output-a-corresponding-translation-using-javascript/31320601?noredirect=1#comment50628725_31320601) a was able to get the job half done.

Here is my code so far (reduced to the absolutely necessary):

```css
span.ko:hover + #kanahelfer-ko {display: block;}

#kanahelfer-ko { 
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="ko">こ</span>

<div id="kanahelfer-ko">ko</div>
```

So far it does what it is supposed to do. The problem is, that i need many of these divs (a little more than 200, one for each kana).
But ist does not even work with two:

```css
span.ko:hover + #kanahelfer-ko {display: block;}
span.re:hover + #kanahelfer-re {display: block;}

#kanahelfer-ko { 
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

#kanahelfer-re { 
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="ko">こ</span><span class="re">れ</span>

<div id="kanahelfer-ko">ko</div>
<div id="kanahelfer-re">re</div>
```

I hope anybody can help me.

P.S.: Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Your + (adjacent sibling) selector will only select *adjacent* siblings. Once you add another span in between the your original span and the div, they are no longer adjacent. Try changing "+" to "~" (~ is a general sibling selector)

Comment: \o/ works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
span.ko:hover + #kanahelfer-ko {display: block;}
span.re:hover + #kanahelfer-re {display: block;}
```

To:

```
span.ko:hover ~ #kanahelfer-ko {display: block;}
span.re:hover ~ #kanahelfer-re {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think dgavian found your problem - if you wanted to you could easily do what you're trying to do with pseudo elements.

```
<span class="ko">こ</span><span class="re">れ</span>

.ko:after {
    content: "ko";
    display: none;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    position: fixed;
} 
.re:after {
    content: "re";
    display: none;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    position: fixed;
}

span:hover:after {
    display: block;
}

span {
    display: inline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jhev6w10/